# Sub Sigma-Algebra and measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

If a random variable $X$ is measurable with respect to a sub $\sigma$-algebra (let's say $\beta_{1}$), such that $\beta_{1}$ $\subset$ $\beta$  , is $X$ -necessarily- measurable with respect to the main $\sigma$-algebra $\beta$ ?

My intuition would be YES, since every point in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra would have an inverse image in the $\sigma$ algebra $\beta$. but the converse would not be true. 
Am i correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Let $(\Omega, \beta, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $\beta_1\subset\beta$ a $\sigma$-algebra. If $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is $\beta_1$-measurable, then for each Borel set $B$, $X^{-1}(B)\in\beta_1\subset\beta$, so $X$ is $\beta$ measurable.

Clearly the converse is not true (just take any non-degenerate random variable and $\beta_1=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$).